# Avoiding automatic closure of open HTML elements with DOMDocument::saveHTML

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, domdocument

I am aiming to add custom data attributes to `div` and `ul` containers if that container uses a specific class. I start from HTML fragments that contain either valid HTML (a full `div` with its contents and a closing `</div>`) or just the opening `div` (without its contents and a closing `</div>`).

Here is an example of content I may start with:

```html
<div id='gallery-7222-1' class='gallery galleryid-7222 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail'>
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```php
// grab all containers from the HTML.
$dom_doc = new DOMDocument();

/*
 * $html here can be the example I posted above.
 * LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED and LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD are used
 * to avoid adding a doctype and wrapping the whole output in HTML tags.
 */
$dom_doc->loadHTML( $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

// Let's look for lists and divs.
$ul_tags  = $dom_doc->getElementsByTagName( 'ul' );
$div_tags = $dom_doc->getElementsByTagName( 'div' );

/*
 * Loop through each ul, and add the data.
 * I do more things in there, like checking for what class the ul has,
 * but I've simplified things here. 
 */
foreach ( $ul_tags as $ul_tag ) {
    $ul_tag->setAttribute( 'data-foo', 'bar' );
}

/*
 * Loop through each div, and add the data.
 * I do more things in there, like checking for what class the div has,
 * but I've simplified things here. 
 */
foreach ( $div_tags as $div_tag ) {
    $div_tag->setAttribute( 'data-foo', 'bar' );    
}

// Save our updated HTML.
$html = $dom_doc->saveHTML();
```

The returned HTML includes the new data attribute, but also a closing `</div>` that I don't really want here. You can see it here:
https://ideone.com/sVfAOn

I first thought about just removing that closing `</div>` with `substr`, but I can't do that:
- In some cases, my original HTML does actually include a closing div tag that I want to keep.
- Sometimes I may be editing a string that includes an `ul` instead.

How would I go about stopping `saveHTML()` from being that smart here, and from trying to fix my HTML for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot convince the HTML parser not to parse HTML. The best solution would be rethinking your approach to how you get the data in the first place, and ensuring you don't get fragments.

Failing that, you could try treating it as XML first to see if it breaks:

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom_doc = new DOMDocument();
$remove = "";
// try loading it as xml
if (!$dom_doc->loadXml($html)) {
    // it failed, get the error message
    $err = libxml_get_last_error()->message ?? "";
    // is it because of an unclosed element?
    // find out which element it's breaking on
    if (preg_match("/end of data in tag (.*?) /", $err, $matches)) {
        $remove = "</$matches[1]>";
    }
}
$dom_doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// do stuff

$html = str_replace($remove, "", $dom_doc->saveHTML());
```

Of course this assumes that you're dealing with HTML that is otherwise clean and won't trigger a bunch of other errors. If that were the case, you'd need to go checking through `libxml_get_errors()` for an unclosed element error.

Comment: > The best solution would be rethinking your approach to how you get the data in the first place

Yes, I opted to go in that direction as well, it requires a bit of refactoring but ends up being a bit of a cleaner solution. 